# How do I install Python2.7 in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install Python2.7 for educational purposes in Ubuntu 12.10. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: It should be installed by default in 12.04, 12.10 and 13.04.  What's the output of `python --version`

Comment: Zero research effort in this question.

Answer (score 4):

It is installed by default. You don't need to do anything extra to install it.

Python is not an "application" so to speak. It's a language, and the Python 2.7 interpreter is installed by default. You can run it in the terminal to get an interactive shell for the interpreter. If you are waning to learn to program in Python, I'd recommend using the `python3` interpreter instead, and starting from there, as new code really should be written in Python 3.x at this point.

You can run `/usr/bin/python3` to get the default Python 3.x interpreter, or `/usr/bin/python` for the default Python 2.x interpreter.

Comment: Okay, I must admit I am a novice. I am trying to figure out how to run the application. Can I do this via the terminal or by searching for the requisite file?

Answer (score 1):

As @dobey said, its already installed on your box. Just open up a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `python`.

You might also want to try `bpython`. Its just a fancy interpreter for python.

you can install it by

`sudo apt-get install bpython`

The thing which I love the most is its autocomplete feature. Most of the times, I dont even google these days :)

http://bpython-interpreter.org/screenshots/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but is Python accessed directly in the terminal?

Comment: `python` is basically a compiled program which can be invoked from the terminal directly. Yes you are correct.

Comment: You are welcome... :) Please accept the answer, if it really helped you.